# Quote on too good to be true model performance

Tags: machine-learning, references, model-evaluation, application, data-leakage

I seem to recall that there is a nice quote by some (well known?) machine learning expert about too good to be true model performance. The quote is something like "If your model performance looks too good to be true, then you either made a mistake or the problem is so easy that you do not need machine learning."

I have a situation where this quote would be very pertinent and want to use it, but I cannot track it down. Who said (or wrote) it and in which context?

Maybe there's even multiple nice statements on this topic that I could cite, which have different ways of putting it.